# how to check the value of pointer (void) not be zero (Attempt to dereference a generic pointer)

Tags: c, pointers, null, segmentation-fault

Sorry it must be very simple question , but since I tried in diffrenet ways without any success I have to ask here to be sure.
C programming :

There is a struct name `rtg`.
EDIT: type of mtch is LLIST
type of initial is LL_NODE
typr of obj is pointer (void)

.
Using gdb when I check

```
(gdb)  print *rtg->mtch->initial->obj
Attempt to dereference a generic pointer.


(gdb) print rtg->mtch->initial->obj

$10 = (void *) 0x4cc660
(gdb) x 0x4cc660
0x4cc660:       0x00000000
```

This null pointer causes segfault in my program. What I am looking for is simply how to check the value of what rtg->mtch->initial->obj is pointing not be zero? (to prevent above segfault) I mean if I check with
`if (rtg->mtch->initial->obj)` , it would just check if pointer obj , adress not be zero (this is not what I intend , I intend to check the value of that pointer not be zero (but when I use * before checking in gdb it says "Attempt to dereference a generic pointer".
So what is the correct way to check that value not be zero (and prevent this segfault)?

Edit : i had tried this

```
if (*((char *) rtg->mtch->initial->obj) != NULL)
```

but i got compile warning :

> warning: comparison between pointer and integer

EDIT2 , here what are these defined in the source code

ECM_REQUEST is struct
ECM_REQUEST rtg;
in this struct defind mtch as LLIST mtch;

initial is LL_NODE

obj is a pointer
i want to check obj value not be zero

so now everything are clear about my question isn't it?

Thanks

Comment: You must show more code, like the structure declarations. Don't talk about them, show them.

Comment: `rtg` isn't a struct; it appears to be a pointer to a pointer to a struct. `obj`, once you get to it, appears to be of type `void*`, which means it's illegal to dereference it. gdb tells you that the 32-bit object at the address `obj` points to has an all-bits-zero representation. That's all we can tell without seeing more of your source code.

Comment: @Keith Thompson , yes exactly  , it's a pointer to a pointer to a struct. obj , what i am looking for is , checking the value of that pointer not be zero in-order to prevent that segfault i did tried to check with `if ( rtg->mtch->initial->obj != NULL && *rtg->mtch->initial->obj = NULL)` but this is not correct , how could i correct it

Comment: What about just `(gdb) x rtg->mtch->initial->obj`?

Comment: @alk result of gdb output is : 0x4cc660:       0x00000000

Comment: Yes `rtg->mtch->initial->obj` is pointing to at least four 0-bytes. Isn't this that what you wanted to known?

Comment: no it's not known issue for me , well , i tried this : `*((char *) rtg->mtch->initial->obj) != NULL` m but i got compile warning warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: @nimatajfar, drop the `*`, it means that you read the value pointed to by `obj` which you then compare with `NULL`.

Comment: @lindydancer , thanks , now compile warning is not happens , but i am not sure if this sentence would surely prevent the value of obj is referring not be zero , does it? (in edit2 , i made clear , every type ,rtg is struct , mtch is LLIST ,   initial is LL_NODE , obj is a pointer

Comment: is there any difference checking beetween `*((char *) rtg->mtch->initial->obj) != NULL`  and this one  `rtg->mtch->initial->obj) != NULL`

Comment: You really should show us the **original** code lines that cause the segmentation violation!

Comment: Dear @nimatajfar probably you should go back and read about references, types, pointers, dereferencing the latter and arithmetics on them. Doing so you might also discover the mysterious meaning of `NULL`, what it is and how it is to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is because the left hand side is a dereferenced `char *` (in other words, a `char`) and the right hand side is a null pointer constant, in the form of a `void *`; You're converting a `char` value to a `void *` value... Perhaps you meant `char **`?

```
void *o = rtg == NULL                ? NULL
        : rtg->mtch == NULL          ? NULL
        : rtg->mtch->initial == NULL ? NULL
        : rtg->mtch->initial->obj;

if (o != NULL) { /* ... */ }
```

... Do note that it should be safe to change the type of o to any other object pointer (eg. your question seems to suggest `char **`?)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dereference a generic pointer. The only solution I can think of is to make a temporary pointer to integer to check the value. Basically

```
int *tmp = rtg->mtch->initial->obj;
if (*tmp != 0)
/* the rest of your code here */
```

A cast could also work, but having a temporary pointer makes the code easier to read in my opinion.